# The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) gets exception " could not open database"

Tags: android, database, logcat

I am trying to create an instance of database . That is why I have the following ocde :

```
public class ContactFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private static final String THIS_FILE = "ContactFragment";
    ImageButton new_contact ;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    List<CONTACT_ITEM> contactBody;
    int MODE_PRIVATE=1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactDatabase",null);


    //    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists constants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, number text , extension text);");

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactdialer, container, false);

        contactBody = getReadFromDatabase();
        new_contact = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        new_contact.setOnClickListener(this);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        arrayAdapter=new ContactAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_item_contact,contactBody);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    List<CONTACT_ITEM> getReadFromDatabase()
    {
            List<CONTACT_ITEM> contact = new ArrayList<CONTACT_ITEM>();
            return contact;
    }

}
```

But I am getting exception on the follwing line :

```
 database = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactDatabase",null);
```

The logcat giving the following exception :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:829)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:814)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:709)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:724)
            at com.csipsimple.ui.contacts.ContactFragment.onCreate(ContactFragment.java:38)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why am I getting this error ? How can I solve this ? Any advice is of great help .

Answer (score 0):

public abstract SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)

Open a new private SQLiteDatabase associated with this Context's application package. Create the database file if it doesn't exist.

Parameters
name    The name (unique in the application package) of the database.
mode    Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions. Use MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING to enable write-ahead logging by default.
factory     An optional factory class that is called to instantiate a cursor when query is called.
Returns

Throws
SQLiteException     if the database file could not be opened.

openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)
Use

```
    database = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactDatabase",0);
    database = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: If I use database = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE); then compiler shows cannot resolve method openOrCreateDatabase(String ,int):